# Exclude Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display recent posts from regular posts section and custom post types, excluding one custom taxonomy term from each custom post type. But the recent posts section doesn't show anything.

```
   <?php 
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query(
     array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'miss_behave', 'emily_davies','gemma_patel','poppy_smythe' ),
    'category__not_in' => 4,
    'tax_query'          => array(
    'taxonomy' => array('miss_behave_category','emily_category','gemma_category','poppy_category'),
    'terms' => array(141,142,143,144),      
    'field' => 'id',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
        )
        )
    );?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tax_query` is incorrect. `taxonomy` does not take an array.

```
taxonomy (string) - Taxonomy.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters
```

You will need to rewrite your arguments to be more like [the following from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can automate that a bit:

```
$taxonomies = array('miss_behave_category','emily_category','gemma_category','poppy_category');

$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'post', 'miss_behave', 'emily_davies','gemma_patel','poppy_smythe' ),
  'category__not_in' => 4
);

$args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) {
  $args['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => $tax,
    'terms' => array(141,142,143,144),      
    'field' => 'id',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
  );
}
// var_dump($args);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

However, "categories" are a taxonomony so you may as well include them in with the rest of the taxonomies, and all those `NOT IN`s are not likely to be very efficient. I would carefully consider where those need to be included.