# How to create a loop inside WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I want print array in a loop and want to put it inside `WP_Query`.

Is it Possible? If there are other alternatives kindly mention it.

```
    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'Subscriber', 'fields' => 'all',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    // Here I want to create a loop
    // loop will start from here repeating the array
    array(
    'key'       => 'user_group_name',
    'value'     => 'Panera Group 2 Encino',
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
    // loop end
    /*array(
    'key'       => 'user_group_name',
    'value'     => 'West Hollywood',
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),*/
)));
```

Comment: You are asking a pure PHP question, really: "How do I create an array dynamically?" Its not inherently WordPress. One example of doing that is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142490/21376

Comment: Please merge your accounts and stick with one only

Answer (score 1):

Just construct what you need outside of the main query.

```
// terms to search
$meta_query_keys = array('Panera Group 2 Encino', 'West Hollywood');

// start the meta query off
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

// add terms to query
foreach($meta_query_keys as $key) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'user_group_name',
        'value'   => $key,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}

// construct main query
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array('role'       => 'Subscriber',
          'fields'     => 'all',
          'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    ));
```